# Spring Cache configuration to variable int as key in @Cacheable annotation

Tags: java, configuration, ehcache, spring-cache

How can I configure Spring cache to accept an int variable as a key?

I tried the following but has not worked. I did read in the API, and I saw that the value for the key must be string. So I'm not 100% sure what is the properly configuration

I tried use this annotation in my method:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames="GETREQUIREMENTPRIVATE", key = "#RequirementID")
private Requirement getRequirement(final int RequirementID, final Connection connection)
```

And I did set this in my ehcache.xml file:

```
<cache name="GETREQUIREMENTPRIVATE"
statistics="true"
         maxElementsInMemory="1000"
         eternal="true"
         memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
</cache>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Integer` for the key, but not primitive `int` there should is Object because for getting String key will use .toString() method. So `Integer`, not `int`.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitrii , So just changing to Integer the key automatically convert to string ? or I would need add something like toString in the key?

Comment: You just use Integer or Long key and all will well)